# Improvement in python script involved in solving euler n°357

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I know that this is a weird and annoying question, but I hope that Christmas atmosphere will make the work easier to be done.
In a few words: I have tried to write a python script aimed to solve Euler problem number 357, which says: "Find the sum of all positive integers `n` not exceeding 100000000 such that for every divisor `d` of `n`, `d+n/d` is prime."
So I wrote this python script and I tried to improve it many times, even by searching on the Net.
And eventually I managed to make it more than ten times faster, however it cannot go through 100M numbers, even after 24 hours of runtime(yes, i tried).
So this is the script: I'd like to know if there's anything wrong or what makes it go so slow. Ignore comments because some of them are in my own language.

```
#Find the sum of all positive integers n not exceeding 100000000
#such that for every divisor d of n, d+n/d is prime.

import time
maximum=100000000

def isprime(n):
    # range starts with 2 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n
    for x in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%x==0:
            return False
    return True

#main()
start=time.time()
final=list()
for n in range(1,maximum):
    counter,d=1,1
    divisors=list()
    while d<=(n**0.5): #Mettendo d<=n, e poi sotto range(len(divisori)/2) ci si mette il DECUPLO del tempo
        if n%d==0:
            divisors.append(d)
        d+=1
    for divisors_index in range(len(divisors)):
        prime=divisors[divisors_index]+n/divisors[divisors_index]
        if isprime(prime)==True:
            counter+=1
        elif isprime(prime)==False:
            counter=0
            break
    if counter==(len(divisors))+1:
        #print "%d:%s--->%d"%(n,divisors,len(divisors))
        final.append(n)   
end=time.time()-start

print "Results: %d. Time: %f seconds"%(len(final),end)
```

P.s: In the Net I have found a solution in Haskell, then ported into C (which i know a bit). The fact is that the solution looks pretty identical to mine; anyway I did not try to look at it in detail because I did not want spoilers(actually I want them now).
Thank you and Merry Christmas.

Comment: have you tried using C? I would expect it to be much faster as it is compiled (vs. Python which is scripted..)

Comment: It's solvable in Python, I'm quite sure of it.

Comment: i think your main problem here is that you find divisors `d` from scratch for every `n`, even though many will be multiples of `n` you have already examined.
ive found these problems are best done in order.  if you've done a project euler problem involving the sieve of Eratosthenes, or are at least familiar with the concept, see if there is a way to use that as an optimization.  sometimes you can trade space for time.
There is also room for more mathematical (rather than algorithmic) improvements - ie. it is quite easy to prove that any number of form `a^b` with `b>1` does not fit the criteria

Comment: Euler problems usually require at least one "observation", or "aha! moment" to solve them in reasonable time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't build up a list of divisors and then test them all. Test each as you find them, and skip the number as soon as you find an invalid one.

Another way to phrase the problem: "the sum of integers n not exceeding 100000000 such that there are no divisors d where n/d + d is composite". We can express this much more simply in Python, by first creating a function that tests for a divisor with a composite some, and then using built-in functional-programming tools. This is generally a bit more efficient than iterating over the lists directly, and will also automatically implement "early-out" logic (i.e. stop testing a number as soon as we find a divisor with a composite sum).

```
import time
maximum = 100000000

def isprime(n):
    # We can use those same tools in the prime tester...
    return not any(n % x == 0 for x in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1))

def divisor_with_composite_sum(n, d):
    return n % d == 0 and not isprime(d + n / d)

start = time.time()
result = sum(
    n for n in range(1, maximum)
    if not any(
        divisor_with_composite_sum(n, d)
        for d in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1)
    )
)
```

Now it just remains to optimize how we find the prime numbers and the divisors :)

---

EDIT: Upon further thought. This is an Euler problem; you're supposed to have something more clever in mind than brute force.

Every number that qualifies will have each prime to the power 1 in its prime factorization. Proof by contradiction: suppose for some prime `p`, `n` is divisible by `p^2` (or a higher power of `p`). Then `p` is trivially divisible by `p`, and `n/p` is divisible by `p` (by the assumption), so the sum is divisible by `p` and therefore composite. Further, every number that qualifies is 1 less than a prime, because `1` is always a divisor.

So: build a list of primes up to 100000000 (see Amadan's answer for example, and see if you can apply the above techniques too ;) ). For each of these, subtract 1, and check if the result has a duplicated prime factor. If not, then you can do a more detailed test.

Comment: After all of this filtering, I was wondering if the 'detailed test' is still necessary. It turns out it is. 66 is 1 less than a prime number and has no square factors, but 2*33==66 and 2+33=35 (which is divisible by 5).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your spending a huge amount of time in your isprime function. Perhaps using some extra memory, and using a prime sieve to store a in a list whether each number is prime at the beginning would help a little.

You may even be able to optimize further, by generating a list of prime numbers, and divisors at the same time, using an algorithm very similar to a sieve.

Answer (score 1):

I claim that you are spending a lot of time in your isprime method. Here are two possibilities that come to mind to improve on that front:

- Generate a (sorted) list of primes (using eratosthenes sieve or something) and lookup numbers instead of executing that loop to test whether a number is prime.
- Build a cache for isprime lookups: whenever you determine whether a number is prime or not, save the result in a list/dict/whatever. Before calling isprime, check if you already tested that number by looking in your list/dict/whatever.

The second suggestion is not quite as efficient as the first, but is very easy to patch into your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                       

def primes(ubound):
    ubound = ubound + 1
    a = [False] * ubound
    p = 2
    primes = []
    while p < ubound:
        primes.append(p)
        for n in range(p, ubound, p):
            a[n] = True
        p = p + 1
        while p < ubound and a[p]:
            p = p + 1
    return primes

print primes(100000000)


$ time erastothenes.py > results.txt
real    1m32.441s
user    1m14.866s
sys     0m4.588s
```

It's still somewhat sluggish, and it probably could be improved further; I'm no expert in Python. Maybe with native arrays. I don't know how to make one without first making a list, which is a waste of time.

(Yeah, I know I'm wasting the first two array positions. :p )

**EDIT** With algorithmic optimisations @DanielFisher talked about (and not wasting space):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                       

def primes(ubound):
    size = (ubound - 3) / 2
    a = [False] * size
    s = 0
    primes = []
    while s < size:
        t = 2 * s
        p = t + 3
        primes.append(p)
        print p
        for n in range(t * (s + 3) + 3, size, p):
            a[n] = True
        s = s + 1
        while s < size and a[s]:
            s = s + 1
    return primes

primes(100000000)

$ time erastothenes.py > results.txt
real    0m36.737s
user    0m35.725s
sys     0m0.864s
```

Comment: You can save some time by starting to tick off only at `p*p`. More by not including even numbers in the sieve.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about cutting the thing by half, saves a lot of memory *and* time (2 takes about 8 seconds, not counting skipping over even elements and double-size list init). But I wanted to show the sieve algo - algorithmic optimisation would make it less readable. I still want the pythonic optimisations :)

Answer (score 1):

You spend much too much time collecting the divisors.

To find the divisors, you check every number not exceeding `n**0.5` whether it divides `n`. So that's `sum([int(n**0.5) for n in range(1,maximum)])`, approximately `6.7*10**11`, divisions. That takes a *lot* of time. The slow `isprime` function is a relatively minor problem, since most of the time it will quickly find the candidate to be composite.

A Haskell solution using what looks like the same algorithm can be much faster because Haskell is lazy. The list of divisors is only computed as far as required, so most numbers will be eliminated after having calculated only *very few* divisors, which is done quickly. In Python, you can achieve that with generators (yield).

To get a speedier programme, the suggestion of JeffS to simultaneously sieve primes and divisors (sieve only divisors, the primes/primality test follows automatically from that) is a good first step. More can be gained by doing a bit of mathematical analysis of the problem. Find a few relatively easy *necessary conditions* for the numbers. You will find that there aren't too many numbers to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up your isPrime function significantly with a change like this:

```
from itertools import count

def isPrime(n):
  # eliminate multiples of 2 and 3.
  if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
    return False

  limit = n ** 0.5

  for i in count(1):
    # all other primes take the form 6k +- 1.
    # though not all values of k produce a prime.
    high, low = 6*i + 1, 6*i - 1

    # we'll never find a factor greater than the square
    # root isn't composite and which would be ruled out
    # by earlier tests.
    if low > limit:
      return True

    # if we find a factor, it's obviously not prime.
    if n % low == 0:
      return False
    if n % high == 0:
      return False
```

That can be further improved by caching the list of primes.  The sieve is actually quicker (I believe) but this is straight forward and easy to work with.

Comment: A sieve, if correctly (not necessarily optimally) implemented, will be much faster indeed.